# Draw a line Using to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

I would like to know how to draw the red line using JavaScript?

The red line is straight and it is started by pressing a button.

Comment: JavaScript alone can't do that. You'd need some sort of drawing like element, say a `<canvas>` or `<svg>`. And here we expect you to show the code you tried which didn't work. No code yet? Then you should start there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome :)

Following is an example of how to draw a line using canvas in JavaScript. Hopefully it'll be useful for you

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(200,100);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Reference: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp)

Comment: Thank!! :) Your answer to me
 help a lot!!!

Comment: no problem! I'm glad it helped you!